# JavaScript ensure all numbers are unique and if not plus one (or more)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, d3.js, duplicates

I'm trying to place some labels on a d3 chart.

I have a `DATA` object with a `DATA.rowOffset` value for each. Basically my code calculates the `DATA.rowOffset` and sets it like this: `d.rowOffset = Math.floor(d.total/heightSquares);` but sometimes the `rowOffset` is the same and so the labels render on top of each other.

I need to cycle through this `DATA` and check for duplicates and then just +1 any duplicates.

I tried a method that looked at the previous `.rowOffset` and then added 1 to the current `rowOffset`, but that doesn't work if there are more than 2 duplicates.

I'm sure there's an easier way.... perhaps.

Edit: here's some code I tried mainly `if (d.rowOffset === DATA[i-1].rowOffset) d.rowOffset++;` so it checks the previous row offset. I think I need to cycle through all the data and then restart the cycle if a duplicate is found.

```
DATA.forEach(function(d, i) {
      d.amt = +d.amt;

      d.units = Math.floor(d.amt / squareValue);

      sumTotal = sumTotal + d.units;
      d.total = sumTotal;



      d.rowOffset = Math.floor(d.total / heightSquares);

      if (i > 0) {
        console.log(DATA[i - 1].rowOffset);
        if (d.rowOffset === DATA[i - 1].rowOffset) d.rowOffset++;
      }
```

Comment: So what if you had `[2, 2, 2]`? Do you expect `[2, 3, 3]` or `[2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: [2, 3, 4] so all values are unique and the labels just stack below each other if they try to go on the same line. thanks

Comment: Can you show the code for the method that you tried?

Comment: @phocks Ok, that actually adds a layer of complexity to your problem because every duplicate that's incremented could become a duplicate of another number and this must be accounted for. I added one possible solution, hopefully, it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach you can take.

You initialize an empty [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) data structure to keep track of unique values you've encountered so far. You iterate through the array and for each value do the following:

- If the value was previously encountered, increment it until it doesn't match any previously encountered values
- Update the encountered values to include this new value
- Replace the old value with the new value

Here's how that would look in code:

```js
function incrementDups(arr) {
  // a set of encountered unique values
  const encounters = new Set();

  // increment each duplicate until it has no duplicates
  return arr.map(num => {
    while (encounters.has(num)) {
      num += 1;
    }
    encounters.add(num);
    return num;
  });
}

console.log(
  incrementDups(
    [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4] // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  )
);

console.log(
  incrementDups(
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  )
);

console.log(
  incrementDups(
    [1, 99, 55, 4, 55, 2] // [1, 99, 55, 4, 56, 2]
  )
);
```

The solution above has quadratic worst-case time complexity. The input that generates this situation is an array containing only duplicates, for example `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, where the last iteration of the nested `while` loop will run `N` increments. Despite that, on average, this algorithm should perform quite well.

A further optimization could be made by using more space to remember the last increment value for a certain duplicate and use that as the start value for incrementing, rather than the number itself.

Right now, the code above actually does a fair amount of repetition. If we had `[2, 2, 2, ...]`, for every `2` we would start incrementing from through `2`, `3`, `4`, etc. even though technically the previous `2` already did our work for us. Ideally, we want the first `2` to start counting from `2`, the second `2` to start counting from `3`, etc. This will be particularly useful for large arrays of consecutive values. For example, if we had `[1, 2, ... 99, ... 2, 2, 2, 2 /* 100 times */]`, using the first algorithm, each `2` would count from `2` to `99` plus how ever many increments to the next unique value. On the other hand, using this new approach only the first `2` would do this. The next `2` would just increment `99` to `100`, the next one `100` to `101`, and so on. If we were given an array of only duplicates as before, `[1, 1, 1 ...]`, each `1` would only need to get incremented once now rather than going through the entire range.

This tightens the time complexity to `O(N*max(array))` which is still quadratic but only depends on the range of values, not the number of duplicates like before. It is also more optimized for your particular situation since you will expect an array of low numbers that are close to each other in value.

To keep track of this info, we can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of a number to the latest unique value it was incremented to.

```js
function incrementDups(arr) {
  // a set of encountered unique values
  const encounters = new Set();

  // a map of the last unique non-duplicate for each value
  const lastNonDup = new Map();

  // increment each duplicate until it has no duplicates
  return arr.map(num => {
    let updatedNum = lastNonDup.has(num) ? lastNonDup.get(num) : num;
    while (encounters.has(updatedNum)) {
      updatedNum += 1;
    }
    encounters.add(updatedNum);
    lastNonDup.set(num, updatedNum);
    return updatedNum;
  });
}

console.log(
  incrementDups(
    [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4] // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  )
);

console.log(
  incrementDups(
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  )
);

console.log(
  incrementDups(
    [1, 99, 55, 4, 55, 2] // [1, 99, 55, 4, 56, 2]
  )
);
```